# Why do I get this result when merging small polygons

Tags: postgis, geotools

I would like to merge small, thin polygons to continuous polygons a when they intersect.
This is a section of the original polygons:
[image: original polygons]
And this is my result:
[image]
I'm using this SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) 
FROM "orgPolygons"
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: (Your query is going to create one multipolygons of all polygons, wether they intersect or not). But that doesnt explain you problem

Comment: Impossible to answer without test data.

Comment: Sorry, the viewing projection is WGS84, some polygons has a lage distance between the vertices, and straight lines will be drawn, the result has more vertices on those "lines" and will follow the earth more correct when viewing.